# how to delete specify string in C#

Tags: c#

When i program,i want to delete a specify string in a long string.

For example:

The source string is:

```
abcdffff<fdfs>adbcccc
abcdffff<fdferfefs>adbcccc
abcdffff<fdffefes>adbcccc
abcdffff<fdffefefs>adbcccc
```

The i want to delete the string like `<fdfs>`

The result should be:

```
abcdffffadbcccc
abcdffffadbcccc
abcdffffadbcccc
abcdffffadbcccc
```

How could i do?

This is my code:

```
public string formatMailMessageBody(string herf,string notifyinfo)        
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(notifyinfo.Replace("〈%〉", "") + "<br><br>");
            sb.Append("单击下面的链接查看您当前任务：<br>");
            sb.Append("<a href='" + herf + "'><b>" + herf + "</b></a>");            
            string s = sb.ToString();
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Is it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the following code is applicable only if the string you want to delete has this format `<...>` (no other pairs of `<>` inside):

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\<[^>]*\>", "");
```

The `Regex` class is located in the namespace `System.Text.RegularExpressions`.